# The QSqlQuery returns exceptions for the words starting with some digits

Tags: c++, qt, sqlite, exception, qsqlquery

I have this code:

```
foreach (QString TheKeyword, KeywordsList) {
    if (!TheKeyword.isEmpty())
    {
        TheKeyword.replace("'","''").replace("[", "[[]");

        QString sQuery = QString("UPDATE news SET deleted = '1' WHERE %1 like '%%2%' AND Id IN(%3) AND deleted = '0'")
                            .arg(TheColumn)
                            .arg(TheKeyword)
                            .arg(TheIDs);

        QSqlQuery TheQuery(TheDB);
        TheQuery.prepare(sQuery);
        TheQuery.exec();

        if (TheQuery.lastError().isValid())
        {
            qDebug() << TheQuery.lastError() << "   -   " << TheKeyword;
        }
    }
}
```

For example, the "**KeywordsList**" contains this word's list (The "KeywordsList" is a QStringList):

```
1Tap
World
A man from Mars
2 Battery
2Do
1CLICK
01 Net
2 Bananas
4 Bananas
system app remover
```

My code returns this errors:

```
QSqlError("", "Unable to fetch row", "No query")    -    "1Tap"
QSqlError("", "Unable to fetch row", "No query")    -    "2 Battery"
QSqlError("", "Unable to fetch row", "No query")    -    "2Do"
QSqlError("", "Unable to fetch row", "No query")    -    "1CLICK"
QSqlError("", "Unable to fetch row", "No query")    -    "01 Net"
QSqlError("", "Unable to fetch row", "No query")    -    "2 Bananas"
```

So, I see that problem is only with the **keywords starting** with '**0**', '**1**' or '**2**'

I tried to use **bindValue**, but without success.

Thank you.

Comment: Forget manually assembling a SQL query with strings like this -- it's how you guarantee an [injection attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Focus on learning how to use prepared statements.

Comment: @MrEricSir Thanks. I don't care for security, because it's a personal desktop application.

I used before the **bindValue** method, but doesn't work.